# Парсинг на клиенте

Tags: javascript, html

Необходимо на **клиенте** получить данные с другого сайта.
Нужная информация на странице другого сайта хранится в

```html
<div id='1'>дежурный</div>
```

Как реализовать?

Comment: Пример:  
На данной странице есть `<a id="nav-users">Участники</a>`, хочу запустить файл.html который выведет содержимое данного тега. И который можно будет использовать на других устройствах без установки дополнительного ПО. При этом использовать CORS нет возможности.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так примерно, однако в общем случае может помешать [`CORS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), поэтому тут используется публичный прокси, для этих же целей Вам придется настроить проксирование для этого запроса на своем сервере:

```js
let req = (url, selector, target) => fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + url)
  .then(r => r.text())
  .then(r => {
    let tmp = document.createElement('div');
    tmp.innerHTML = r;
    console.log(r)
    tmp.innerHTML = tmp.querySelector(selector).innerHTML;
    document.querySelector(target).appendChild(tmp);
  });

let url = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/';

req(
  url, 
  '#question-mini-list h3 a', 
  '#one'
);
```

```html
<div id="one" style="color:red"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо.
Правильно понимаю что нет никаких хитрых способов это сделать на клиенте в обход CORS?

Comment: @РоманВасилаки подробнее опишите юзкейс

Comment: Добавил подробности.

Comment: @РоманВасилаки изменил ответ - воспользуйтесь прокси

Comment: Почему `let`, a не `const`?)

Comment: @Arthur мне кажется что для примера это не принципиально =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, да.. может показаться как придирка, действительно, без разницы)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  
"воспользуйтесь прокси"  
-Не умею, поэтому и задал вопрос. Хотя бы направьте куда копать.

Comment: @РоманВасилаки я добавил проксирование в ответ