# не работает кроссдоменyый запрос ajax JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Не работает кроссдоменный ajax запрос, ругается на CORS!
Интересует решение на нативном JS!

```
let returnObjectFromJSONRequest = function(url) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var output = {};
        request.open('GET',url, false);
        request.withCredentials = true;
        request.send();

        if (request.status === 200) {
            return output = JSON.parse(request.response);
        }

        return output;
    };

let data = returnObjectFromJSONRequest('http://www.mrsoft.by/data.json');
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Сайт mrsoft.by вам не принадлежит? Тогда никак, сайт запрещает кроссдоменные запросы.

Comment: `net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

Comment: @andreymal есть публичные прокси https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/978408/188366

Comment: @StrangerintheQ только авторизации там не будет